# NHibernate insert generates updates for collection items

Tags: c#, nhibernate, insert, nhibernate-mapping, has-many

How should I configure my mappings to avoid NHibernate updating my child entities' foreign keys right after inserting them?

E.g. Parent class is mapped like this:

```
class ParentMap : ClassMap<Parent>
{
    public ParentMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id)
           .GeneratedBy.Increment();
        Map(x => x.Name);

        HasMany(x => x.ChildNodes)
           .KeyColumns.Add("Parent_id")
           .Cascade.All();
    }  
}
```

Let `Parent` have a bunch of `Child` objects:

```
Parent p = new Parent("test");
p.ChildNodes.AddRange(GetSomeDummyNodes());
```

When I save the parent entity, generated SQL looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Parent] (Name, Id) VALUES (@p0, @p1); @p0 = 'test', @p1 = 0

INSERT INTO [Child] (Name, Id) VALUES (@p0); @p0 = 'child1', @p1 = 0
INSERT INTO [Child] (Name, Id) VALUES (@p0); @p0 = 'child2', @p1 = 1     
INSERT INTO [Child] (Name, Id) VALUES (@p0); @p0 = 'child3', @p1 = 2

UPDATE [Child] SET Parent_id = @p0 WHERE Id = @p1; @p0 = 0, @p1 = 0
UPDATE [Child] SET Parent_id = @p0 WHERE Id = @p1; @p0 = 1, @p1 = 0
UPDATE [Child] SET Parent_id = @p0 WHERE Id = @p1; @p0 = 2, @p1 = 0
```

If I use Guid.Comb as Id column generator, there are no updates, foreign keys are set in `INSERT` statements immediately. But since I am using the `Increment` strategy (which also creates IDs on the client side, and there is no `SELECT` statement which would read the ID value from the database, I don't see why IDs couldn't be set immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'll have to take a look at the 'Inverse' mapping attribute.

```
HasMany(x => x.ChildNodes)
           .Inverse()
           .KeyColumns.Add("Parent_id")
           .Cascade.All();
```